# How to clean up intersecting faces and edges?

Tags: mesh, modifiers

I'm currently trying to build grid structures by using planes and solidifying them. Problem is, when I use this to create hexagonal grids, the solidifying modifier does this in a way that faces of the same mesh intersect each other:

[image]

Above object started out as three planes which were joined to a Y-shape, then solidified.

You can see that in the middle, the upper faces actually cross each other.

Is there an easy way to clean this up in a way that…

a) …where the faces intersect each other, edges and vertices are created
b) …the inner parts of the faces are removed?

To clarify, I am working with planes, because I am warping them, which works far easier than dealing with already solid meshes (hard to explain I guess… My point is that I really don't want to change my underlying workflow, if I can help it). And since I'm working on grids, where this phenomenon occurs *often*, having a way to automate this would be really helpfuL.

Here is a picture that better illustrates what I want to achieve (right), as well as my current workflow(File is in a comment below):

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Edit: As your request has changed I give a second answer below.

Maybe you're not choosing the best way to build your object, in your case the *Solidify* modifier will create unwanted intersection and it will be hard to fix.

What you could do for example is begin with a triangle (3 vertices circle), extrude it up, then select the 3 faces, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>E</kbd> to extrude, choose *Individual* Faces and drag to extrude.

[image]

Second answer:

- Create a 10 vertices circle, scale one of 2 vertices so that it makes a hexagon.

[image]

- Move down those vertices, extrude down the whole mesh.

[image]

- Select one of 2 edges underneath, bevel them, extrude down.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. You're probably right that there has to be a better way, but your approach doesn't work for me, because I want to warp the planes in three dimensions. Maybe I'll add a picture later. A friend suggested building the negative spaces, then using boolean on an object to remove them. This sounds like a pissi le approach

Comment: to warp the planes in three dimensions? Yes please give more explanations, I don't see how what you've done could work better than my solution

Comment: Here you go, this illustrates my current workflow: https://www.mediafire.com/file/xkeh2a0ymead2gl/untitled_001.blend/file I assume you are right and there is an easier approach. I didn't even mention the open parts on top of the mesh...

Comment: so you should have directly asked how to do the final shape, maybe edit your question with a screenshot    ;)   I'll try to find out

Comment: ok, edited, tell me if this is correct

Comment: I first assumed your answer was right, but it left out a crucial part: in your solution, the faces are triangular and therefore planar. If you take a look at the object with the subsurf modifier, you'll see how the face is distorted. This is not easy to spot in a picture, but if you move the object around, you can see it. I now rebuilt the whole thing and kept the planes as separate objects to which I applied the modifiers. They now still have overlapping faces, but I think I can manage this better. Still, thank you very much for your input and time.

Comment: You mean as soon as you give it a subsurf it doesn't work? I didn't you wanted to give it a subsurf, I think it can easily be fixed, I'll take a look later  ;)

Comment: No, the subsurf doesn't seem to be the problem. I think the core problem is that when you have an object with connected, but open planes, as the planes have an inner and outer side, the solidify modifier orients itself along this. But since the planes are all open, there is no actual "inner" face. Come to think of it, a dirty hack might be to put two planes in the same space, but give them opposing normals... Edge cases, edge cases everywhere.

Comment: It's very hard to understand, maybe edit your question with more details if you want help   ;)

Comment: Well, I think what we discuss here is outside of the scope of the original question, which was "how to deal with intersecting faces and edges". The answer seems to be "it's complicated", which is fair enough. I think I've found a process with which I can avoid the problem in the first place. This is not a solution per se, but I can live with that. Thanks again for your time.

Answer (score 0):

…ok, after playing around with it some more, the way to go for me is to use the edge split modifier to treat the different planes as separate meshes when applying the solidify modifier.